# What to use instead of div?

Tags: html

In the WHATWG [HTML specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) it says regarding to the div element that we must strive not to use the div element.

It says:

> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

So what should we use instead of divs?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do?

Comment: Literally *right underneath* the quoted section it says "For example, a blog post would be marked up using article, a chapter using section, a page's navigation aids using nav, and a group of form controls using fieldset."

Comment: From the article: "For example, a blog post would be marked up using `article`, a chapter using `section`, a page's navigation aids using `nav`, and a group of form controls using `fieldset`.

On the other hand, div elements can be useful for stylistic purposes ..." What more are you asking?

Comment: `Use of more appropriate elements instead of the div element` ...so it basically depends upon your need ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use what *makes sense* for the structure of your document. If you're writing an article, use the `article` element. Defining segments within a document? Consider the `section` tag. Need to mark the header of a document? Use the `header` element.

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Foo Title Here</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Article content can go here.</p>
    <p>Note how meaningful this document structure is.</p>
    <footer>
        <!-- Links, etc. -->
    </footer>
</article>
```

Think about it, every document starts with semantically meaningful tags: We wrap our HTML document with the `<html>` tag. Inside, we define a `<head>` and a `<body>`. Within the head we provide a `<title>`, perhaps a few `<script>`'s, and link up some stylesheets with `<link>` or `<style>`.

Since everybody follows these rules, it boggles the mind why they would abandon this consistency and favor the use of vague and semi-meaningless tags like `<div>` to define crucial portions of their document.

Contrast a document made up of vague and meaningless tags:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Foo Title Here</div>
    </div>
    <div>Article content can go here.</div>
    <div>Note how meaningful this document structure is.</div>
    <div>
        <!-- Links, etc. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Pretty meaningless, right? Always use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the next line of the referenced specification, they provide some examples:

> For example, a blog post would be marked up using article, a chapter
>   using section, a page's navigation aids using nav, and a group of form
>   controls using fieldset.

So, if possible, you should use an element that have more semantic meaning than the `div` element.